# How does toluene favor ortho/para in terms of kinetic and thermodynamic control?

Tags: organic-chemistry, thermodynamics, kinetics, teaching-lab

If nitration of toluene is carried out at a very low temperature, presumably the reaction would be carried out under kinetic control. During these conditions that favor kinetic products, is more ortho or para formed when compared to normal laboratory conditions?

Comment: Related: [How does toluene react at higher temperatures and why?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/5660/7951)

Comment: @Loong Thank you very much for finding that. Would it be possible to extrapolate that "para" is the kinetic product?

Comment: Is nitration an equillibrium reaction like F-C-alkylation?